# Jooq fetch into a Map using SHOW VARIABLES results

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to use jooq to execute a `SHOW VARIABLES` query for mysql/maria. I'm trying to use jooq only because I have jooq for everything else but this SQL isn't something jooq can "abstract". I could also use jdbc directly but am trying to stay consistent and also learn jooq better.

`SHOW VARIABLES` returns two string columns, `Variable_name` and `Value`.

I've been trying to find a way to get a `Map` of these key/values, but nothing is working.

`Map<String, String> dbVars = create.fetch("SHOW VARIABLES").intoMap(...?)`

Seems like this works, but not sure if there's a simpler way:

```
Field<String> key = field("Variable_name", String.class);
Field<String> value = field("Value", String.class);
Map<String, String> dbVars = create.fetch("SHOW VARIABLES").intoMap(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *"simpler"*, you probably mean:

- No need to declare column names
- No need to declare local variables for `key` and `value` (that's not necessary in your example, though)

You could use this, as an alternative:

```java
create.fetch("SHOW VARIABLES").intoMap(
  r -> r.get(0, String.class), 
  r -> r.get(1, String.class)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying out intoMap but wasn't quite getting it, not sure why but my ide wasn't having it. You're right about not using local vars, I don't really need to. Never a bad day when your question is answered by the jooq author himself.